# watchdog not putting messages in log

Tags: 7, log-messages

I'm trying to write a custom message to my log (viewable at /admin/reports/dblog) using the `watchdog` function.

```
function create_vector_user_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
   watchdog("VECTOR", "inside user mail", array(), WATCHDOG_INFO);
   /* other stuff */
}
```

I have the core database logging module enabled, and the log is set to display all messages. But this message isn't getting saved to the log. I've used a standard php `error_log` just to make sure the `create_vector_user_mail` function is running, and it is. I copied the `watchdog` line from another contrib module that does print its messages correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your hook implementation is being called at all?

Comment: @cilefen - as I said, I used an `error_log` call to be sure it was being called, and it is. I want to use watchdogs because I don't have direct access to the php error logs on our qa and staging systems.

Comment: I guess it would help if I read the entire question! I use watchdog() all the time and that usage looks correct to me. You didn't mention if ordinary system events are making to the log. Are they?

Comment: The code is correct. You should use your logging to capture the array output of `module_implements('watchdog')`; if `dblog` isn't in the array, `dblog_watchdog` isn't be called to insert a log into the DB.

Comment: Watchdog isn't called for AJAX. See if this is relevant: https://grokbase.com/t/drupal/development/094p729s0q/watchdog-does-not-always-work-or-am-i-missing-something